# C++ shared pointer issue

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm trying to create a set function that will take in a shared pointer and set it equal to another shared pointer.

This is the shared pointer and the set function that i have declared on my header file

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape();
    Gdiplus::Point start;   
    Gdiplus::Point end;

    std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> m_pen;

    virtual  LRESULT Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics * m_GraphicsImage) = 0;

    void setPen(std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen2);

    void setStart(int xPos, int yPos);
    void setEnd(int xCor, int yCor);
};
```

but when i try to implement it in my cpp i get an error saying that my "declaration is incompatible with void setPen declared on .h". it also says m_pen is unedintified on my cpp file.

```
#include<memory>
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"

  #include "ShapeMaker.h"
void Shape::setPen(std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen2)
{
    m_pen = pen2;
}

void Shape::setStart(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    start.X = xPos;
    start.Y = yPos;
}


void Shape::setEnd(int xCor, int yCor)
{
    end.X= xCor;
    end.Y = yCor;
}
```

That's literally all i have. the stdax.h includes

```
  #include <atlwin.h>

  #include <atlframe.h>
  #include <atlctrls.h>
  #include <atldlgs.h>
  #include <atlctrlw.h>
  #include <atlscrl.h>

  #include <GdiPlus.h>
```

Errors that I get:

```
shapemaker.h(11): error C2039: 'shared_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'

shapemaker.h(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

shapemaker.h(11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

shapemaker.h(11): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
.h(16): error C2039: 'shared_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'

shapemaker.h(16): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'shared_ptr'
shapemaker.cpp(9): error C2511: 'void Shape::setPen(std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Shape'
```

Comment: Can you show this implementation?

Comment: It would be handy to actually see the line it's complaining about so that we can compare it to the declaration.

Comment: there it goes guys. sorry about that

Comment: So, m_pen and setPen are members of class Shape?

Comment: You did include `<memory>` and `<gdiplus.h>`, right?

Comment: I think at this point, posting the entire .h file, including #includes, and well as the .cpp file is needed.

Comment: And preferably keeping the size of them as small as possible while still getting the errors you're talking about.

Comment: There is almost certainly some `namespace` misuse happening outside of the code that's posted.

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` should be the **first** line of code (I think comments can come before). I hate using them, but as I recall, that's how they work.

Comment: that's literally all i have. this exercise was taken of a book...

Comment: @Chris i changed...still nothing

Comment: no its not @DrewDormann . i have added the list of errors that i've been getting

Comment: @user1665569 Now we have an answer.  The actual errors were important.  You're missing `#include <memory>` in that header.

Comment: @Tushar the filename is ShapeMaker.h and i have included it on the cpp

Comment: @DrewDormann that was it.

Comment: @user1665569 On another note, it's better practice to do imports in the header, and then not repeat them in the cpp file.

Comment: @user1665569 That's good news!  If you hit compilation problems again, the **first, complete, exact** error message you get should be your top concern.

Comment: @DrewDormann he included <memory> in his cpp file, and included his header file after that, it should not cause the errors, since compiler compiles header and cpp together, just wondering why.

Comment: @JiuDong See my newly posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm posting my answer from the comments for any visitors.*

The problem is at the beginning of the cpp file.

```
#include<memory>
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"

  #include "ShapeMaker.h"
```

MSVC++ demands that the precompiled header `"stdafx.h"` precede any other code in your source files.

The `#include<memory>` must be removed, and instead placed in `"ShapeMaker.h"` where it is first needed.